# back button go back to another activity not the one i define it in the manifest

Tags: android

I need to define EditProfileActivity as the parent activity to  EditActivity to enable the back button in tool bar in the EditActivity but it is not working

note : the back button back to the activity that was open before the parent activity "EditProfileActivity"

```
    <activity
        android:name=".controllers.drawer.AgendaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".controllers.EditProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".controllers.EditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit"
        android:parentActivityName=".controllers.EditProfileActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".controllers.EditProfileActivity" />

    </activity>
```

i call editActivity from EditProfileActivity:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, EditActivity.class);


    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.edit_name:

            intent.putExtra("toolBarTitle", "Enter your name");
            intent.putExtra("editText", tvName.getText().toString());
            break;

        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: From where, you are starting EditActivity?

Comment: @atifali from button in EditProfileActivity

Comment: Post your code where you starting EditActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
public void onClick(View view) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, EditActivity.class);


    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.edit_name:

            intent.putExtra("toolBarTitle", "Enter your name");
            intent.putExtra("editText", tvName.getText().toString());
            break;

        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you  very much , sorry i don't have reputation more than 15  to vote for your answer

Comment: Now you reputation is 16 and you can do it.